# Dealing with padding when using `Integer.toBinaryString()` in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-operators

I want to implement Method2 for this problem http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-non-repeating-elements-in-an-array-of-repeating-elements/ but I have one issue. I dont know how have to divide the numbers from the array in two groups (ones that have '1' at specified position in their binary representation, and ones that dont have) I thought that I have to use `Integer.toBinaryString()` for each number in the array with the following method:

```
private static boolean hasOne(int number, int i) {
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
    if(s.charAt(i) == '1')
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But the problem is that not every numbers have the same length in their binary representations and the method doesnt work correctly. How can I handle this? I.e. how can I deal with the padding?

Comment: Most of this can be readily ported to Java. Almost nothing in the second for loop has to change (save for the pointer stuff)

Comment: @user3371223 If you are trying to get the nth digit from the right hand side, not the left. Can you use s.charAt(s.length-(i+1)); And any i>=s.length is false

Comment: @Ben This is in Java. I dont know C++. My question is how to divide the numbers into two groups (the ones that have '1' at specified position and the rest) because my idea, that uses the above method, doesnt work correctly.

Comment: java can do bitwise operations. You need the number that signifies any bit set in the xor, `set_bit_no` in their example, and you bitwise-AND this with each number to see if that number has this bit set. That's your partition.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very close to what you've got. Let's say you're checking for a binary value at position `6`. That would be..

```
0101011
------^
```

Easiest thing to do is, before you check if the value is `1` or `0`, just check that the `size` of the binary string is larger than the index.

```
if(s.length() <= i) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're having trouble taking the extra step of explicitly converting to binary and finding the set bit there, just know that the provided code ports simply to java, since it's mainly bitwise operations:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 2, 3, 11};
    int xor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        xor ^= arr[i];
    }
    int set_bit_no = xor & ~(xor-1);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] & set_bit_no) != 0) {
            x ^= arr[i];
        } else {
            y ^= arr[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x); // prints 7
    System.out.println(y); // prints 9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can pad your binary string with a combination of `String.format` and `replace`:

```
String s = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(number)).replace(' ', '0');
```

You can also use bitwise operators in order to determine whether a given number's binary representation has a 1 in a certain spot.

For example, consider the decimal number `x = 20`, which is `10100` in binary. Further suppose that you want to determine whether the binary number has a 1 in the third spot from the right `n = 3`. You can use bit shifting `>>` to shift the binary sequence to the right two times `n - 1`, and then mask `&` it with 1.

The resulting expression will look like `(20 >> 2) & 1`, and will evaluate to one if there is indeed a 1 in the third spot from the right, or a zero if it doesn't. In this case, it evaluates to 1.

So you can further generalize this to:

```
private static boolean hasOne(int number, int i) {
    return ((number >> (i - 1)) & 1) == 1;
}
```

You can learn more about bitwise and bitshift operators in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).